# Skip csv columns when copying to Cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to import some data from a csv file to Cassandra using the cql `COPY FROM` command.

The csv file has more columns than I am interested in, so I wanted to skip some columns when importing.

For example, I have the following columns on the csv

```
id, name, age, salary
```

And I want to add only columns **id, name and salary**

Is there any way to do this using only `COPY FROM` parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SKIPCOLS` option by specifing the list of columns you don't want to import.

According this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html), you can run a command like :

```
COPY <table_name> FROM <file_name> WITH SKIPCOLS = 'age'
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have large amount of columns, you can import columns particularly in this format:

```
COPY keyspace.columnfamily (column1, column2,...) FROM 'test.csv';
```